# I use reset --HEAD in git I want my recent files to be deleted

Tags: git

In my master I have 3 files. And in my develop I have 2 files added. In my develop I have done many commits and added many files say `one.txt` `two.txt` `three.txt`.
Now I did `reset --hard HEAD~5`.

I want my rest of the files to be deleted and the only files before the `HEAD~5` to remain.
It is not allowing me to push the files and again and again saying to pull them first.
If I pull the files then the files will be again added to my local machine(i.e `one.txt`,`two.txt`, `three.txt`)  which I don't want to.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If git tells you to pull after a git reset --hard, it is simply because the push is not a fast-forward one: you are modifying the history published on the remote repo.

If you are sure that nobody else would be surprised by the change of history of that remote branch, you can do a:

```
git push --force
```

You would then see those files being deleted as well on the remote repo side.

Comment: Hey VonC can you help me with one more problem.
When I am merging my two branches , the files are getting lost sometimes.
Can you tell me why this is happening and how to overcome from this.
Because we use git to have a version backup of my files.

Comment: @astha if a file is deleted in one branch, and that branch is merged to another, the deletion would be reported to that other destination branch.

Comment: That's the point. After merging the two branches. I cant see one of my file anywhere. Its lost somewhere.

Comment: @astha It would be best to ask a separate question with a more detailed exemple of the issue in it (as well as the OS and exact version of Git used)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764609/while-merging-two-branches-my-files-are-getting-lost

@VonC  visit here pls.

Comment: I am new over stack overflow. Can you tell me from where to accept this answer.

Comment: @astha sure: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, (and take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour)