# while merging two branches. My files are getting lost

Tags: git

I am having two branches names as master and develop. Both branches consist of some files in it. 
When I merged develop to master, one of my file got deleted. 
I don't understand how it got deleted when I didn't put any delete command.
I am using git version: 1.9.5.msysgit.1  and Windows 8.

Comment: By "adding a bit more details", I meant OS, Git version, `git log` of the file in the `develop` branch, `git status` after the merge...

Comment: Did you have the same file with different case (lowercae, upercase) in each branch before merging?

Comment: What is your current merge strategy?

Answer (score 0):

When the branch `develop` removed this file after it branched off, then a merge of `develop` into your line (e.g. into `master`) would introduce this effect there as well.